# Mongodb case insensitive $pull from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection name employer, below are some example documents

```
[{
"companyName" : "XYZ Corp",
"employee" : [
    {
        "name" : "john smith"
    },
    {
        "name" : "john doe"
    }
 ]
 },
 {
  "companyName" : "ABC Corp",
  "employee" : [
    {
        "name" : "Marco Doe"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Mark smith"
    }
  ]
  }]
```

Now I want to write a case insensitive query I will provide companyName and employee name and want to pull that employee name from employee array.
I have written a query like

```
db.employer.update({companyName: { '$regex': /^ABC Corp$/i }}, {$pull: {employee: {name: '/^mark smith$/i'}}})
```

Consider employee name will store in any case. Above query is not working, it's not pulling corresponding employee name `mark smith` from array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example,

```
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
```

You can also read the full documentation or see more Mongodb regexp examples [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

I think you don't just search for a `{field: /regex/i}` you need to specify every field that uses regex separately.

Hence your code should be,

```
db.employer.update({companyName: { '$regex': /^ABC Corp$/i }}, {$pull: {employee: {name: {regex: /^mark smith$/i}}}})
```

Name field will also be searched according to regular expressions.

As your code above was only using regexp on `companyName` field and not name field.

Also, remember to remove quotations in regexp patterns.
Note from comments (Thanks, Johne).

Comment: Modified query will be db.employer.update({companyName: { '$regex': /^ABC Corp$/i }}, {$pull: {employee: {name: {$regex: /^mark smith$/i}}}})

Comment: Sure, as there are no quotations in regexp patterns. Thanks @JohneDoe!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. :)

```
db.employer.update(
  {
    companyName: { 
      '$regex': /^ABC Corp$/i 
    }
  }, 
  {
    $pull: {
      employee: {
        name: {
          regex: '/^mark smith$/i'
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```